# Change value in array without traversing whole array in Java?

Tags: java

For example : If my array is `arr[5] = {5,2,1,5,8};`

So if I have to change all 5's to -1 , the possible way is Check each and every element , `if value==5` , then change it to -1 .

Is there any alternate way in JAVA ?

I found solution in C using Array of Pointers , but not in JAVA .

Here is c code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

 void main()

{
int i ;

int a[7] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};

int *ptr[5] = { &a[2] , &a[5] , &a[1] , &a[5] , &a[5] } ;


printf("The value of array is :\n");
for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{

    printf("%d  ",*ptr[i]);

}printf("\n");

//////Now changing 5 ot -1 I require only one step , not to traverse entire    ///array , Here the step is : 

a[5] = -1 ;

///final array is :
for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{

    printf("%d  ",*ptr[i]);

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to do an alternate way

Comment: How did you do it in C "with pointers"??

Comment: Array of pointers will still require full scan.

Comment: What how does the solution in C do it? Please link. I'm interested.

Comment: Algorithm theory says that you can't do better. You HAVE TO traverse the whole array to ensure that every 5 becomes -1.

Comment: I suppose you could, earlier on, produce a list of offsets representing 5s, and then just traverse that collection.

Comment: `Arrays.fill(arr, -1)` will definitely change all `5`s to `-1` without checking the elements. But I guess it will violate a constraint of you task you didn’t mention…

Comment: You can do the same thing in Java, only slightly more clumsy.  You'd need to define a mutable Integer class, the use an array of object references.

Comment: @I.K. Well , I did not get idea suddenly , my project needs minimum complexity , and should be implemented in JAVA after C , and the actual problem is having 2D array , so when I have to change from a to b , then complexity would be O(n^2) , but after using Array of pointers , only one step needed to solve it . So aim of asking this question is Implementation of same code in JAVA , because I am beginner learning JAVA .

Comment: And what do you do if you want to change the `5`s to `2` and then change the `2`s to `9`s? Also what do you do, if you had values that aren't in such a small interval, e.g. `arr[5] = {-10000,2,1,5,999999}`?

Comment: The C language is a completely different beast compared to Java. In fact, Java was designed to avoid what C and C++ allow in terms of allowing explicit access to memory as you have done in your C solution. As lodo indicates, in Java you can't do better than to traverse. If you want to write convoluted code to get around traversing then look at the monstrosity that fabian wrote just to achieve the same. Now ask yourself, which is less complex: writing a simple for loop to traverse or @fabian's solution. This kind of code works for small arrays but not for arbitrarily large arrays.

Comment: @I.K. - One can do pretty much the same as the C solution, except that you have to use instances of a custom class rather than individual `int` values.  Clumsier, but topologically the same.

Comment: @fabian  , in my actual case , the range is limited and having consecutive integers only , and I am using for loop to initialize value.

Comment: Thank you all , as I cannot use @ multiple times in my content , so I would like to write @all , and because of conversation in comments and all answer , i can answer my own question . Thank you once again .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've stated it, no. You would have to sort the array or use some other structure to be able to find all 5s easily and change them.

Your array of pointers reveals what you were thinking though: You can accomplish this if you have an array not of `int`s, but of mutable Objects that encapsulate `int`s. Then, if all `5`s are represented by the same Object, you can mutate that object to mutate all the `5`s in the list. If what you really wanted was an array of `int`s however, this is not the correct solution, due to the problems of ensuring that all `5`s are the same object, and the inefficiencies of encapsulating them.

Update based on question update:

My guess of what you were doing was exactly right. The Object I suggested is equivalent to your `int` pointer that you used (in fact, all Objects are pointers, though they point to more than just an `int`). You can see the same problems that I pointed out for this solution in your C code: It only works if you point to the elements of `a`, if `a` contains every possible number in the array, and if you don't need to insert any `5`s into the array afterwards (as trying to go to `5` sends you now to `-1`). Really, you did not solve the problem as you thought you had. There are some circumstances in which this type of solution might be useful, but modifying an arbitrary `int[]` is not one of them.

Comment: and how would you find this magical object in the array that represents 5?

Comment: @I.K. Depends on implementation; at worst you'd just partially traverse. The whole solution is just my stab at the XY Problem based on his comment; with the question as written it's not efficient, as I said.

Comment: @I.K. , I use Array of pointers in C code , that I Included after editing , this can be achieved without traversing whole array , only one step needed .

Comment: @DamanJha Your solution is exactly equivalent to what I suggested, and doesn't work as well as you think it does. See my update.

Comment: Thank you all , as I cannot use @ multiple times in my content , so I would like to write @all , and because of conversation in comments and all answer , i can answer my own question . Thank you once again .

Comment: @DamanJha Much welcome. If this answer solved your solved your problem, make sure to *accept* it by clicking the checkmark below the vote count :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it faster than looping through all indices, you need additional data. One Example would be using a [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). But the time required to create that data would be longer that iterating through the whole array.

The inverted index would map the values to the indices, i.e. for `arr = {5,2,1,5,8}`:

```
1 -> {2}
2 -> {1}
5 -> {0, 3}
8 -> {4}
```

#### Create index

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> invertedIndex = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int val = arr[i];
    List<Integer> l = invertedIndex.get(val);
    if (l == null) {
        l = new LinkedList<>();
        invertedIndex.put(val, l);
    }
    l.add(i);
}
```

#### Replacing values

```
int numToReplace = 5;
int newValue = -1;
//--------------------
List<Integer> l = invertedIndex.remove(numToReplace);
if (l != null) {
    // replace numbers in arr
    for (int index : l) {
        arr[index] = newValue;
    }
    // update inverted index
    List<Integer> l2 = invertedIndex.get(newValue);
    if (l2 != null) {
        l2.addAll(l);
    } else {
        invertedIndex.put(newValue, l);
    }
}
```

#### Change single element

```
int index = ...;
int newValue = ...;
//-------------------
int oldValue = arr[index];
List<Integer> oldList = invertedIndex.get(oldValue);
oldList.remove(index);
if (oldList.isEmpty()) {
    invertedIndex.remove(oldValue);
}
List<Integer> l = invertedIndex.get(newValue);
if (l == null) {
    l = new LinkedList<>();
    invertedIndex.put(newValue, l);
}
l.add(index);
```

Comment: Thank you all , as I cannot use @ multiple times in my content , so I would like to write @all , and because of conversation in comments and all answer , i can answer my own question . Thank you once again .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without traversing then may be not a suitable data structure. Use `Map` instead like the following way -

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

After that you can put number into them like this -

```
map.put(5,5);
map.put(2,2);
map.put(1,1)
```

Comment: NO! If you have multiple identical values how would you find them all to replace them?

Comment: You could use a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` to map `value -> List(indexes)`

Comment: @I.K. , I just forgot about it. Thanks for reminds me.

Comment: @Alexis C. , I think it could be a nice solution in this case. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Thank you all , as I cannot use @ multiple times in my content , so I would like to write @all , and because of conversation in comments and all answer , i can answer my own question . Thank you once again .

Answer (score 0):

Decided to put my two cents in. Certainly not more efficient but if the asker is looking for alternate solutions here you go!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //52158
    int[] arr = {5,2,1,5,8};
    String strArr = Arrays.toString(arr);
    strArr = strArr.replaceAll("5", "-1");
    strArr = strArr.replaceAll("\\[", "");
    strArr = strArr.replaceAll("\\]", "");
    strArr = strArr.replaceAll(",", "");
    strArr = strArr.replaceAll(" ", "");
    ArrayList<Integer> endArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length(); i++){
        if (strArr.substring(i, i + 1).equals("-")) {
            endArr.add(Integer.parseInt(strArr.substring(i, i + 2)));
            i++;
        }
        else endArr.add(Integer.parseInt(strArr.substring(i, i + 1)));
    }   
}
```

I just converted to a string the replaced them all then converted it back. Yes almost completely useless and you'd have to be very naive to implement this solution but it's different because I used string manipulation vs array manipulation. I know not much different but, it is.

Comment: Thank you all , as I cannot use @ multiple times in my content , so I would like to write @all , and because of conversation in comments and all answer , i can answer my own question . Thank you once again .

Answer (score -1):

Use a data structure which keeps values sorted in descending order.  Then traverse just until you find the 5's. Change those values. Viola, you didn't traverse the entire array, though you might wind up doing more work anyway.

I suggest a max-heap. In Java, a `PriorityQueue` would do what you want.

Though know this isn't going to operate more efficiently than just traversing the array a single time.  Keeping an ordered data structure and performing operations on it are time consuming.

Comment: If the rules of the game allow you to invent new data structures, then you can just wrap an array and flip a switch that says `interpret5asMinus1`.

Comment: Who said those were the rules of the game? OP isn't exactly giving us a lot to go on @aioobe

Comment: Thank you all , as I cannot use @ multiple times in my content , so I would like to write @all , and because of conversation in comments and all answer , i can answer my own question . Thank you once again .

Answer (score -1):

Java only use pointers, but you don´t see it. For this, you need taversing all array or do it another.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, you seem to have misunderstood the question; this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thank you all , as I cannot use @ multiple times in my content , so I would like to write @all , and because of conversation in comments and all answer , i can answer my own question . Thank you once again .